# Help - MEV Contract

Tags: metamask, contract-debugging, smart-contract-wallets, recovery, mev

I created an deployed a MEV bot via remix.re — after deploying the contract — I noticed the internal transaction sent to an unknown address.

Any help on seeing what happened here??

My Contract Address
https://etherscan.io/address/0x4685F20Ce35CB9a61759c89D721323577F85Fe89

Contract sent to
https://etherscan.io/address/0x4ba622d38aadc1505a9a95dd5a034c1340082c18#internaltx

Original Code
https://pastes.io/raw/tuxyzxquyh

Answer (score 1):

This is a scam, don't deploy it and don't send money.

Notice the callMempool(), parseMempool() and mempool() functions, their function is not related to any mempool but is an obfuscated and very elaborate way to generate the scammer's wallet address.

I'm afraid the funds sent have been lost.